# React Native Stack Navigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, stack-navigator

I have a scenario where I have 2 Stack Navigators containing 2 screens each. Something like below:

```
const Page1 = StackNavigator({
      Screen1: {
         screen: Screen1
      },
      Screen2: {
         screen: Screen2          
      }
});

const Page2 = StackNavigator({
      Screen3: {
         screen: Screen3
      },
      Screen4: {
         screen: Screen4          
      }
});
```

Can I jump from **`Page1 Screen2`** to **`Page2 Screen1`** ? 
Also to explain why I have 2 StackNavigators is that there is a limitation where the **`Page1`** flow happens before **`Page2`** flow and once **`Page1`** flow is complete, the user won't be able to see it again.

I initially created only one StackNavigator but there is a limitation where the initialRouteName cannot be set based on props (Corrent me if I am wrong)

Answer (score 0):

Screens name have to unique.

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('screenname');
```

at your scanerio:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate(Screen1);
```

which screen it is going to?